# How to build Android SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

i need help on building Android SDK for linux ubuntu arm64.

I know there are some people providing Android SDK for arm64 but those are for Android mobile. Then i tried those SDK (SDK for Android mobile or Android SDK for Termux) but  adb etc are not working. I want it for linux arm64 ubuntu.

So I hope you guys will help me to build Android SDK for arm64 linux.

Thank you in advance.